# What is the name for this time series rank plot?

Tags: python, data-visualization, terminology

[image]

from:https://2020.stateofjs.com/en-US/technologies/front-end-frameworks/

What is the name of this type of chart? How can I create the same chart in python ?

Comment: The sigmoid elements are at best decorative and at worst gratuitous.

Comment: How to do this in any particular software is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

This type of chart is known as the **Bump Chart**. Once you know the name, there are plenty of articles/tutorials on how to implement it in python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095438/how-to-make-a-bump-chart

Comment: Trivium: Bumps chart from bumps races (Google if unfamiliar) was an earlier name, and is in my view preferable. The popularity of that name in recent decades likely owes most to mentions in Tufte's books.  Naturally, you can call it what you like. Brinton has examples under no soecific name from ~1900 in his 1914 book, and no doubt the idea is older yet.

Comment: @NickCox There's an even earlier example from the 1883 statistical atlas based on the 1980 US  decennial census: https://www.datadeluge.com/2015/01/the-earliest-ever-slopegraph-1883.html But I don't think it was given a specific name there either.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks. That's the 1880 census being reported on.